# Mixed usage of the sequence parser and the expectation parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

**[> qi::double_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edec982146f7eb0c) v.s. [>> qi::double_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a28577f3ef3529f9)**

I want to parse the following string

```
    "***: @a_-091 , *** 1"
```

to a struct defined as

```
    using type = boost::fusion::vector<char, int, double>;
```

When the parser

```
    *qi::omit[qi::char_ - '@'] >> '@' >> qi::char_ >> '_' >> qi::int_ >> *qi::omit[qi::char_ - qi::digit] >> qi::double_
```

is used, the result is OK. However, the result is totally different with the following parser

```
    *qi::omit[qi::char_ - '@'] >> '@' >> qi::char_ >> '_' >> qi::int_ >> *qi::omit[qi::char_ - qi::digit] > qi::double_
```

The following is the sample code.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
    #include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

    using type = boost::fusion::vector<char, int, double>;

    int main() {
        std::istringstream istr{
            "***: @a_-091 , *** 1"
        };

        std::vector<type> data;

        namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
        istr >> std::noskipws >> qi::match(*(
            *qi::omit[qi::char_ - '@'] >> '@' >> qi::char_ >> '_' >> qi::int_ >> *qi::omit[qi::char_ - qi::digit] > qi::double_
            ), data);
        // istr >> std::noskipws >> qi::match(*(
            *qi::omit[qi::char_ - '@'] >> '@' >> qi::char_ >> '_' >> qi::int_ >> *qi::omit[qi::char_ - qi::digit] >> qi::double_
            ), data);

        for (size_t i = 0; i != data.size(); ++i) {
            std::cerr << data[i] << "\n";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

PS:
The problem has been solved by the link proved by *cv_and_he* in the comment. It is caused by the mixed usage of ">>" (the sequence parser) and ">" (the expectation parser).

Comment: Two suggestions: one question per question, and code must be in the question. And describe the code, describe what it's doing (or not doing) and what you expected instead. (And comments go into the comment section, not in the question.)

Comment: @Mat Thanks. Look forward for further suggestions.

Comment: You talk about two things that do different stuff. Yet you show only one piece of code and describe neither.

Comment: @Mat I don't quite understand. As you suggested, I remove a problem asked. Now, the problem is the different behavior betwwen ">>" and ">".

Comment: Why would you expect the same thing when using two different parsers? What behavior exactly don't you understand? What results are you getting and what were you expecting?

Comment: @Mat Yes, they are different parsers. When ">>" is used, the double is parsed succesfully. Thus, ">" should successed as well. I think the only difference between the two parsers is that ">>" allows failure, but ">" does not (throw an exception instead).

Comment: Explain all that _in your question_.

Comment: I believe your problem is similar to the one described [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Unexpected-behavior-using-versus-tp4662087p4662134.html).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a88056650c51580b

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/705d921eaf86a031) also works, but it's awful.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hint, perhaps you can rewrite using `>>`.

To still have the expectation points you can perhaps write

```
a >> b > c
```

like

```
a >> b >> (c > eps)
```

I will test this later